# Layout above another

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to create this page in an Android application:

[image]

By now i ends up with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:text="My App"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="24dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                         android:id="@+id/default_text_layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

                     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                         android:id="@+id/default_text"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:singleLine="true"
                         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                         android:id="@+id/default_text_layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

                     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                         android:id="@+id/default_text"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:singleLine="true"
                         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                         android:id="@+id/default_text_layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

                     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                         android:id="@+id/default_text"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:singleLine="true"
                         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The result is this:

[image]

The problem is that when the keyboard is focused I've got this result, placing adjustResize in Manifest:

[image]

Do you know how:

1) avoid to cover the inputs when the keyboard is focused
2) place the button like the first figure(above the bottom margin)

If you have any suggestion on how to improve the xml would be great, since i'm new with android xml.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can wrap your whole layout with `ScrollView`

Comment: I'm using a nested scroll view on the top of that, this is just the fragment layout, therefore I cannot use the scrollview. I've already try to not put everything in linear layout and works fine, so I think is because the linear layout the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) I didn't have any problems without `adjustSize` in manifest
[image: screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:text="My App"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="24dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_text_layout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/default_text1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_text_layout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/default_text2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_text_layout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/default_text3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_text_layout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/default_text4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_text_layout5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/default_text5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

2) Try to use `ConstraintLayout` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)) to create flat layout instead of hierarchical (it's better for your app performance)

Comment: If i don't use adjustResize the button is cover by the keyboard, that's why I used the flag.
I'd love to use constraint layout, but i wouldn't know how to set the two layout that create the background(the one blue and the one white). 
Do you know how to set like a 50% layout in constraint layout?